# How do python classes-pointers automatically fill attributes?

Tags: python, class, pointers

I'm having really hard time understanding how pointers to classes work. Suppose we have a node from a linked list:

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Then if we create a pointer to `x` and create another node `y` and assign it to `x.next`, we'll be able to preserve `x.val` in the pointer and have `y` in `.next` attribute:

```py
x = ListNode(3)
headNode = x
y = ListNode(4) 

x.next = y 
print(f'ID of y: {id(y)}')
print(f'Current x.next:\n\t.val: {x.next.val}\t.next:{x.next.next},\ncurrent headNode.next.next: {headNode.next.next}\n')
```

This prints out:

```
ID of y: 2656509108560
Current x.next:
    .val: 4 .next:None,
current headNode.next.next: None
```

Now if we do the same and replace attributes in `x` once more, pointer will automatically add another node to `.next` attribute of `.next`:

```py
x = y 
y = ListNode(4) 
x.next = y 
print(f'ID of y: {id(y)}')
print(f'Current x.next:\n\t.val:{x.next.val}\t.next:{x.next.next},\ncurrent headNode.next.next: {headNode.next.next.val}\n')

x = y

print(f'Cached list: [{headNode.val}] -> [{headNode.next.val}] -> [{headNode.next.next.val}]')
```

Which prints out:

```
ID of y: 2656507051616
Current x.next:
    .val:4  .next:None,
current headNode.next.next: 4

Cached list: [3] -> [4] -> [4]
```

I was wondering if this behaviour (automatic fill of `next.next` attribute inside pointer `headNode` from `None` to another `ListNode`) is caused by Python automatically understanding that it is pointing to unique instances (`id(y)` are different) and therefore addressing another `.next` pointer that it can find in the class. I would really appreciate if someone could help me wrap my head around this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain more what behaviour you mean?

Comment: @HamzaNABIL got it

Comment: There is no automatic anything happening here so I'm not clear what you are referring to.

Comment: No , it not automatic to fill `next.next`, this behavior is because you set `x = y`that mean `x` reference to the  `headNode.next`

Comment: You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Python doesn't *have pointers* (although, you can think of references as pointers that get automatically dereferenced).  Everything is an instance of a class. See: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html The appropriate level of abstraction in Python is thinking of *names* that refer to *objects*. A variable is a name in a namespace that refers to an object. An attribute is a name in an object namespace that refers to another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is there is no automatic filling of attributes. At every point, you have set the attribute yourself and the pointers simply point to things that you have manually created.

Let's look at your code and assign our own "memory ids" as "First", "Second", and "Third". After each block, we'll ask ourselves the same three questions. What is x.next? What is x.next.next? What is headNode.next.next? Each time the answer will point to a node we manually instantiated and set.

First block:

```
x = ListNode(3) # x = First
headNode = x # headNode = First
y = ListNode(4) # y = Second

x.next = Y # First.next = Second
```

What is x.next? Well, we know that x points to First and that we set First.next to Second. Therefore x.next is Second which we created as a ListNode with value 4 and a next of None.

What is x.next.next? We know that x.next is Second. We have not set anything for Second.next so it takes the default value of None as set by the ListNode constructor, so x.next.next is None.

What is headNode.next.next? We know that headNode points to First. First.next is Second. So First.next.next is Second.next. Second.next is None.

Next block:

```
x = y # x = Second
y = ListNode(4) # y = Third
x.next = y # Second.next = Third
```

What is x.next? We have x pointing to Second now, and then we set Second.next to Third. So x.next is now Third.

What is x.next.next? It is Third.next which is None.

What is headNode.next.next? headNode still points to First. First.next is Second. Second.next is Third. So First.next.next is Third, therefore headNode.next.next is Third.

Once again, I re-iterate that at every instance, you are referencing something you manually created or set.

Answer (score 0):

No , it not automatic to fill `next.next`, this behavior is because you set `x = y` that make `x` reference the same object as `y`(the old y).

```
x = ListNode(3)
headNode = x
y = ListNode(4) 

x.next = y 
print(f'ID of old y: {id(y)}')


x = y 
y = ListNode(4) 
x.next = y 
print(f'ID of headNode.next: {id(headNode.next)}')
print(f'ID of x: {id(x)}')
print(f'ID of y: {id(y)}')
```

Output :

```
ID of old y: 139130971403312
ID of headNode.next: 139130971403312
ID of x: 139130971403312
ID of y: 139130971402976
```

Notice that `headNode.next` and `x` have the same id as old `y`. When you set `x.next = y`, it is equivalent to `headNode.next.next = y` because `x` now references `headNode.next`.